# Finding all repeating points in a large set

Tags: algorithms, computability

This is a programming question, but I believe there should be a related mathematical theorem, so sorry if it is not broad enough.

Given a large set of points $(X,Y)$ where $1 \le X \le 2000000$ and $1 \le Y \le 2000000$. How to find point or points that repeat $>2$ times. Without writing down every point in the set to mark down occurrences.

All set points are randomly distributed, except points that repeat, those occur multiple times in the set.

Normally it would be easy to spot those points putting each of them on the graph. However, since the set is very large and no visualization can be done I'm looking for a way to approximate a number of occurrences with some sort of reduction algorithm. So any related mathematical problem would be helpful.

**Simplified question:** Given a very list of integers $N$ where $1 \le N \le 2000000$ how to find one or more integers that are probably (with a confidence of $\ge90$%) most dominant in the list, without counting all occurrences of every number.

**Suggested solution:** if anyone stumbles onto similar problem - you can lookup probabilistic data structures for information how to deal with problems like this. Also this problem can be solved in naive way by the answer below.

Comment: Pickiness about terminology:  The definition of a "set" is that there are no repetitions.  If you have a "list" or some other kind of collection that allows for repetitions, you should not call it a set.  This sounds like a problem motivated by programming since in a purely mathematical setting, knowing the collection means knowing how many repetitions of each point there are.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "without writing down every point"? If you don't look at every point in the list at least once, how can you be sure you have found all repeated ones?

Comment: @hardmath - thanks, I will keep that in mind. The question is there any way to calculate repetitions without doing it manually (for example - taking a smaller list, calculating all repetitions and than approximating other repetitions by probability).

Comment: Your Question lacks precision.  From what you describe, there might be a set of points (no repetitions), or there could be one point repeated a thousand times (but all other points appear once), or every point might appear twice.  In most programming contexts one sorts the points (or whatever objects are given) and this reveals exactly how many points are repetitions.

Comment: @DavidK - I can look at every point at least once, but I cannot hold/write the state of each number. I'l put it another way - there is a book, I want to find words that repeats the most, I want to find an algorithm that would allow me to find those words by only writing small amount of information and reading the book. Or technically speaking - data set is way to big to put into RAM and I think some combinatorics can help me.

Comment: @hardmath - yes, I know, but this is exactly my problem - data lacks precision as well. In simple programming approach it would work exactly as you described, however I have never seen approach where memory required is < O(1). In this case I' trying to find an algorithm that would work without sorting entire data set. So I was thinking that there might be a way to approximate which points repeats usually (with degree of confidence based on statistics) and then scan list again to count only those points.

Comment: There seems to be some important context for the problem that you are reluctant to share .  If you explained why "all repeating points" need to be found in fixed space memory, we might be able to advise you a little better.

Comment: Why don't you 'hash' them by putting them in '$(x,y)$' buckets (round $x,y$ to 3 decimal places, for example). If you hit a bucket twice, keep track of it. Hashing is a fairly standard technique for looking for canonical forms.

Comment: @hardmath - sorry for being so vague. I do not want to make it too technical since this is a math forum. Maybe I should update my question. Problem I'm trying to solve is related to memory - standard machine has 8-16GB or RAM memory, now imagine that you need to process data in magnitudes of 1TB or more and there is no way to do in memory sort (because it would require $(2000000*4)^2*2$ bytes to store each value and number of repeats), performance is important and I do not want to write it back to disk. I want to determine probable repeating numbers and just count them in a second pass.

Comment: If there are _many_ repeated points, a random sample might give you a reasonable estimate of how many; I would not call this "finding all repeating points," however, since this does not tell you _which_ points repeat, so you have not "found" them. If the "words that repeat the most" repeat a very large number of times each, random sampling might give you a good list of candidates for "most repeated" word, but again this is not _all_ the repeated words, just the most-often repeated.

Comment: If you want to actually _identify_ all points that occur 2 or more times, you will somehow have to compare each point to most of the others, and with 1TB of data that will take a long time or a lot of memory or both.

Comment: @DavidK - thanks, I'm moving towards what you have described - random sampling. It is easy to know how many points there are, if I know what those points are. What I need is to find a way to determine abnormalities in the noise. After I know points that are abnormal I can just scan data again and count those points. Problem being is that abnormalities are too few to easily find them just by picking random region.

Comment: @copper.hat I thought about that already, unfortunately hash would not be balanced. Let's take for example $P(5,5)$ repeating 100 times in range $1..10000$, however in range $10000..20000$ there are more pairs of the same point or just more points in that region in general, so hash for $10000..20000$ will be hit more often.

Comment: The point is that random sampling will not tell you "what those points are." It will identify a _few_ of the repeating points and will completely miss most of them. Perhaps you are merely using words badly and not expressing the things you really want to say, but the things you _are_ saying are self-contradictory.

Comment: There are not that many points, why not just code something up and try. You have a somewhat vague problem, but very specific objections to suggestions.

Comment: @DavidK - sorry if I'm not making sense. I've simplified question to better represent what I want. I do not see any contradictions. I think it is confusing, because I do not want exact precision, I'm looking for a way to prove with some confidence that a set of numbers statistically dominant in the list just by looking at a small part of that list.

Comment: @copper.hat I have updated question. There is no way to do that using hashes and I can explain in more details why if you want me to. This is the first thing I've tried when started looking into this. Simple programming solutions are not working here, that's why I'm hoping that there is some kind of statistical/combinatorical way of dealing with this.

Comment: The "contradiction" is that in your original question you refer to points that "repeat $> 2$ times," but in the "simplified" question you look for points that are "most dominant in the list." You have not defined what you mean by "dominant," but it does not seem consistent with points that merely occur $3$ times each. If "dominant" is really what you want, and if "dominant" means the point occurs in a significant percentage of all entries in the list, _not_ just "$> 2$," then you might be able to identify dominant points by sampling. What exactly makes a point "dominant"?

Comment: It's OK if the thing you first asked for is not what you really wanted, as long as in the end we're able to see unambiguously what it is you want.

Comment: Suppose your set consists of a whole lot of items, each occurring three times. Then all the input points will be output points, and you'll have to "write down all the points in the set", or at least a third of them (and the remaining 2/3 will all be points in the list you output as well, of course). If that kind of input isn't possible, you need to explain why. If it *is* possible, then it's clear your problem, as stated, has no solution. Help us help you by writing a clear and unambiguous problem statement. Here's one question: are the coordinates of your points all **integers**?

Comment: I'm voting to close, because the "simplified question" is even more vague than the original.

Comment: @DavidK - if all numbers in the list are unique and only one number repeats, then that number is dominant, even if that number repeats only two times. Imagine scattering numbers in the way that each integer value is a point on $X$ axis, now each time that specific integer repeats we put it it on $Y$ axis. Creating a function $f(n)=timesRepeats(n)$. Looking at such plot it would be very easy to tell which numbers are dominant. After that I would need to pick $MAX(Y)$ value and find $X$ for that.

Comment: @JohnHughes - it seems hardmath understand the question pretty well

Comment: "if all numbers in the list are unique and only one number repeats, then that number is dominant, even if that number repeats only two times." Well, then, you are out of luck, my friend. Is it not obvious that there is no way to find that number (and to know that there's no other that has 3 repetitions) without looking at every number in the list (or at least a large majority of them)? Look for ways to process lots of data fast. hardmath's answer is a good start.

Comment: @JohnHughes to answer your question above (if you still interested) - output should not be the points, output should be reduced only to points that repeat. so for $[(1,1), (2,9), (5,2), (1,1), (9,6),(2,9)]$ output would be $[(1,1), (2,9)]$. I was not clear what does it mean *most dominant*, because there is no specific threshold, I'm interested in divergence from normal, so if all points repeats two times and one point repeat 3 times - that's the point I need, to put is simply point that repeats in data stream more often then all others. And yes, all numbers are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do (with two or three passes) is to create a number of "bins" that cover your set of points.  For example, we might think in terms of the original universe $[1,\ldots,20000000]\times [1,\ldots,20000000]$ being subdivided into subsets of a convenient form.

Ideally your 1Tbyte of data would be partitioned into (say) one hundred 10Gbyte subsets.  If the subsets are defined by (say) cartesian bounds $S_{i,j} = [x_i,x_{i+1})\times [y_j,y_{j+1})$, then any repetitions that occur will necessarily occur within one of these subsets.

Now each subset is constructed to fit within your PC's memory, where an efficient sorting algorithm can identify all the repeated elements.

If the points are known to be distributed more or less uniformly throught the "universe", something like the optimal partition of the universe will be easily precomputed.  If the distribution is not uniform and not much information is available apriori about the distribution, then an approach in which we adaptively define the partition might be attractive.

Many ways of partitioning the universe will serve our purpose, as the only real requirement is that repeated points will be assigned to the same bin.

Comment: If the memory size is large enough to store $k$ points, and the original input has $n$ points, and $s = \lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil$, then this will require approximately $s^2$ passes over the input points, one to extract each subsquare, so the runtime looks like $s^2 k \ln k$, which is still $O(n^2)$, which is hardly suprising. (Esp. since, per my comment on the question, the output might have size that's $O(n^2)$.)

Comment: @JohnHughes:  The Question doesn't ask us to compare each pair of points and report the result of those comparisons.  Instead we are asked to identify all repeated items (and if later requirements are credited, to report the number of such repeats).  Perhaps you can give an example of how the output could be much larger than the input?

Comment: @JohnHughes:  Perhaps I failed to clearly state that each bin into which points are placed will by construction contain any duplicates of points in that bin.  We can place points in their assigned bins with a single pass once the boundaries are set.  These "hundred bins" in the case I sketched can be files on disk.  So there is no comparison between pairs of bins, as your Comment outlines.

Comment: Suppose the set contains 1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3, 3, 3, ..., 1000, 1000, 1000 etc. Then we have to report repeats at $1, 2, 3 ... 1000$, i.e., at 1/3 of the points. (I'm showing the example in 1D, but it clearly works in 2D as well).  I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote $O(n^2)$ -- sorry about that. I was assuming that the dataset was *very* large (think of the old days: the dataset lives on tape, for instance), and on a medium so slow that random-access writing to it isn't feasible (again, tape). Then to extract each subsquare requires re-reading the input tape.

Comment: Hence there are $s^2$ passes over the data, one to extract each bin. Sorting the bin of size $k$ takes time $k \ln k$, and from that you can find all duplicates (in that bin; as you observe, any duplicate pair must lie in one bin). BTW, I like your algorithm, and think it's completely reasonable -- I was just pointing out to OP that the runtime analysis still has an $n^2$ if your storage medium either isn't large enough for two copies of the data, or doesn't have a constant time random access.

Comment: @JohnHughes:  All the bins are extracted in a single pass.  To give a simple example, the highest order digit of $X$ and the highest  order digit of $Y$ are used to determine a file `BINxy.DAT` that each point is written to as it is read.  This would work okay if the data is fairly uniformly distributed, but problems will arise if the distribution is lopsided.  Lowest order digit would also work.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath - I think this is not a math question. I'm pretty sure now that problems like these should be solved using *probabilistic data structures* (I will update my question to reference other people). Although you answered in the way that would work (I think) but not necessarily using the best approach for this problem, I still will mark your response as an answer since it more or less provides working solution for this problem.

Comment: Sure, and you could also use something like a universal hashing scheme to avoid dependence on the input distribution. I understood that, **given enough memory**, you could extract all bins in one pass; if memory is limited, then you're in multipass land. As David K observes, the problem turns out to be "find the most frequently occurring value(s)," and I suspect, like David K, that this cannot be done "fast" (certainly not in sublinear time) for inputs where there are only one or two repetitions. Hashing and looking for fullest buckets does it in linear time, of course, but OP dislikes that.